# Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.23, but postcss-preset-env uses 7.0.29

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, postcss, plyr.js

Getting this error "`Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.23, but postcss-preset-env uses 7.0.29. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.`" while I was trying to upgrade Plyr version from 3.5.10 to 3.7.2.